# Can the user edit the plist from outside the app?

Tags: ios, macos, plist

I'm using the UserDefaults to save some persistent data (app's state, not something that needs to be secured). This data (AFAIK) is saved on a plist. Can the user edit this plist outside the app?
I tried it, and while it seems possible, when I run the app it overrides the changes with the last values from the app.
If it's not possible, then what good is the 'defaults write ...' command (via the Terminal)?

This question is relevant both to iOS and macOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you use UserDefaults. UserDefaults is really not much more than a dictionary with a convenient way to read/write to a plist file. You can decide yourself where that file is stored, and therefore whether it is changeable by the user outside the app or not. And you are responsible for reading the values at startup and possibly when they change on the fly.

On iOS, only if you use `UserDefaults.standard`, will the plist file be placed in a location that is accessible and managed by Apple's Settings app. It is still your responsibility to read/write the defaults when appropriate. Not sure how that works on MacOS.

If they are reset on startup of the app, it is likely the app is overwriting them explicitly on startup.

Comment: I'm not using UserDefaults.standard so this is probably why it's not accessible. I couldn't find any documentation of this behavior.
Thanks!